# How to sort averages from lowest to greatest correctly?

Tags: python, csv

This is my code:

```
def calculate_three_worst(input_file_name, output_file_name): #Task4
    with open(input_file_name, 'r') as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        data = list(reader)
    
    averages = []
    for row in data:
        name = row[0]
        grades = [float(grade) for grade in row[1:]]
        average = mean(grades)
        averages.append(str(average))
    
    sorted_averages = sorted(averages, key=lambda x: x[1])
    bottom_three = sorted_averages[:3]

    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        writer.writerows(bottom_three)

calculate_three_worst("C:\\Users\\Tandis\\Desktop\\hh.CSV", "C:\\Users\\Tandis\\Desktop\\tester.txt")
```

The CSV file I opened is this:

```
mandana,5,7,3,15
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara,0,5,20,14
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
Ala,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

And the output of my code is:

```
7,.,5

6,.,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6

9,.,7,5
```

but It must be like:

```
5.0
6.066666666666666
7.5
```

What should I do? I wanted to sort the three worst averages from lowest to greatest. In this case, it must be as shown but it's not. Please don't change my code completely. I want to know how can I solve this problem by fixing my code, not changing it.

Comment: `Please pay attention that my question contains 3 questions`  — it's not going to work this way. Each SO question have to contain 1 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the csv module for something so trivial.

Just open your input and output files in 'r' and 'w' modes respectively. Parse the input file by reading each line and splitting on comma.

Calculate the mean values as you process each line and append them to a list.

Sort the list and output the 3 lowest values to the output file:

```
INFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/hh.csv'
OUTFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/hh_out.csv'

db = []

def calculate_three_worst(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name) as indata, open(output_file_name, 'w') as outdata:
        for line in indata:
            _, *scores = line.split(',')
            db.append(sum(float(x) for x in scores) / len(scores))
        print(*sorted(db)[:3], sep='\n', file=outdata)

calculate_three_worst(INFILE, OUTFILE)
```

The output file will look like this:

```
5.0
6.066666666666666
7.5
```

Comment: You saved my code again DarkKnight! Thank you!

Comment: But can you tell me how to change my own code to achieve what I want? I want to use my own code...

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I sort the averages from lowest (5.0) to greatest (7.5)?

Sort ascendingly instead of descendingly, which is changing

```
sorted_averages = sorted(averages, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

to

```
sorted_averages = sorted(averages, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

or even shorter

```
sorted_averages = sorted(averages, key=lambda x: x[1])
# (Python does sort ascendingly by default)
```

; and changing

```
bottom_three = sorted_averages[-3:]
```

to

```
bottom_three = sorted_averages[:3]
```

> 2. How can I remove the names?

Just remove `name` in this line:

```
averages.append((name, average))
```

which is:

```
averages.append(average)
```

There you have a list of only `average`s

> 3. How can I remove the extra lines between outputs?

I don't know if the code you posted here and the code you really ran are the same, but my attempt with `csv.writer.writerows` printed no extra lines.

To sum it up: You have to change several parts in your code as what I have recommended. They are not too complicated. Happy Pythoning.

Comment: Dear Vu Nguyen, I did as you said (I also had to do this: averages.append(str(average)). because if i didn't the program wouldn't run.) but now the out put is: 7,.,5

6,.,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6

9,.,7,5

what should I do?

Comment: @NegarSeidy Sorry for the late reply. I tried to keep your original code as much as possible. But that does not mean you won't have to twist the code yourself. These are basic Python terms and we are not giving a beginner course here in SO. Thank you for your effort.